# Statistics function fails with a converted pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

`df` is my dataframe and I use `.apply()` on it.

This does not work and produces `Division by zero`:

```
def power_divergence(x): # x is a series here
    s = sp.stats.power_divergence(np.array(x), lambda_="cressie-read")
    return x
df.apply(power_divergence, axis=1)
```

In contrast, this works:

```
def power_divergence(x): # x is a series here
    s = sp.stats.power_divergence(np.array(np.array(x).tolist()), lambda_="cressie-read")
    return x
df.apply(power_divergence, axis=1)
```

The former approach leads to an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.1.0.1371.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\py3compat.pyc in execfile(fname, glob, loc)
    174             else:
    175                 filename = fname
--> 176             exec compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec') in glob, loc
    177     else:
    178         def execfile(fname, *where):

C:\file.py in <module>()
     30     return x
     31 
---> 32 r = target_df.apply(power_divergence, axis=1)

C:\canopy\User\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.pyc in apply(self, func, axis, broadcast, raw, args, **kwds)
   4414                     return self._apply_raw(f, axis)
   4415                 else:
-> 4416                     return self._apply_standard(f, axis)
   4417             else:
   4418                 return self._apply_broadcast(f, axis)

C:\canopy\User\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.pyc in _apply_standard(self, func, axis, ignore_failures)
   4489                     # no k defined yet
   4490                     pass
-> 4491                 raise e
   4492 
   4493 

ZeroDivisionError: ('division by zero', u'occurred at index 123441')
```

Unfortunately, trying to reproduce the error with a simple DataFrame did not work. I defined this one `pd.DataFrame(data=[np.array([0,0,4,0,0])])`, but the problem did not occur.

So my general question is: Is it possible that a DataFrame sets certain parameters that make their `np.array()` equivalent differ from a plain list that is converted to a `np.array()` as well? Please ignore that the test applied usually requires more non-zero results, but in this case it is not the reason for failure.

As requested:

```
a    0
b    0
c    4
d    0
e    0
Name: 123441, dtype: object
```

Comment: When I print it, it is `[0,0,4,0,0]`. Please see my edit.

Comment: the dtype is object, how about `power_divergence(x.values.astype(float), lambda_="cressie-read")`

Comment: Wow, this solved it. It is interesting that all my Arrays worked but that one. I do not know why the input was different, but you provided a working solution. Thank you for pointing to the `dtype`.